# Unable to select "SonarCloud/Quality Gate" in "Require approval from additional services" in branch policies

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, pull-request, sonarcloud

According to the tutorial written on the sonarcloud blog (https://blog.sonarsource.com/integrate-sonarcloud-with-vsts-to-boost-code-quality) and the Azure DevOps lab (https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/sonarcloud/) I should be able to use the outcome of the analysis as a qualitygate for my pullrequest.
Unfortunatly this option does not appear when adding a new status policy.

The code has been analysed in the build and in the buildsummary you can see the outcome from sonarcloud.

The last thing I need to do is add it as an approval pull-request requirement.

Comment: Do you mean that you could not see the SonarCloud / Quality Gate in the drop list while you add policy status. Could you add some screenshots details about this?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Yes, this is exactly what i meant. I'm not entirely sure what you want to see in the screenshot?
Maybe this can help? <img src="https://sonarsource.cdn.prismic.io/sonarsource/258f36be32001036ac140cfb8a63be54e55af08b_vsts-sonarcloud-status-policy.png">

Comment: It's better to show the screenshots about the drop list. In addition, you have been execute the build which analysed the code once right? I ever meet your issue, that's caused by I never execute this build before, after I execute it, it displayed in the drop list.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT I did run the build. And i do have results in sonarcloud and on the bottom of the buildsummary there is a topic "SonarCloud Analysis Report" where a "pass" or "failed" is shown.
I want to know how this option was added to the dropdown list for adding a new status policy. Apparently it is not always added automaticly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is having this issue, I found the solution after some research.

Solution: To be able to select 'SonarQube/quality gate' on the branch policy, you need to run at least once the pipeline that checks your code through a PR.

In other words, add the check pipeline as part of the build validation to your PR policy, create a random PR and let it run. After that you will be able to select it in status check.

Credits to Mickaël Caro on this thread: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/azure-devops-pull-request-quality-gate-status-check/33957/14

Answer (score 1):

After several attempts, changes and other setting tweaks i'd managed to get this operational. I think the problem was solved by creating a new personal access token with only the code read/write option selected.
Now the sonarcloud decoration works (providing comments for codesmells) and the status policy is selectable in the branch security policy settings.

Answer (score 1):

If SonarQube is updating each time you run a build, but when you try to add a PR Status Check via AzDO you cannot see the 'SonarQube/quality gate' option appear in the dropdown list you must then enable 'PR Decoration'.

As a SQ Admin, go-to `General Settings` -> `PR Decoration` -> select the organisation URL and add the AzDO project name and repository name.